# Setting audio file as Ringtone fails everytime

Tags: android, audio, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I know this answer has given many times and this is very simple question but some how I am not able to accomplish it. But trust me I have tried many other different solution but none worked for me,

I am trying to set audio file to my **LeEco Le2** devices which does not have memory card, I am trying other file also to copy from code to device but every time it does not copy anything then same code I am trying on Simulator (Genymotion) then its working fine I am not getting what the actual problem is and where exacytly.

I am trying with so many different code with no success, I got so many link from SO and other forums but any code is not working below link code exactly what I need and I tried that also but this also not working setting audio file as Ringtone.

Below is my code.

```
public boolean saveas(int ressound) {
        InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(this.songidlist[this.currenttrack].intValue());
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fIn.available()];
            fIn.read(buffer);
            fIn.close();
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sounds/media/";
            String filename = "Ring.mp3";
            if (!new File(path).exists()) {
                new File(path).mkdirs();
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream save = new FileOutputStream(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(path)).append(filename).toString());
                save.write(buffer);
                save.flush();
                save.close();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE", Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));
                File k = new File(path, filename);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("_data", k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(PlusShare.KEY_CONTENT_DEEP_LINK_METADATA_TITLE, "RingTone");
                values.put("mime_type", "audio/mp3");
                values.put("artist", "Test");
                values.put("is_ringtone", Boolean.valueOf(true));
                values.put("is_notification", Boolean.valueOf(false));
                values.put("is_alarm", Boolean.valueOf(false));
                values.put("is_music", Boolean.valueOf(false));
                Uri uri = Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
                getContentResolver().delete(uri, "_data=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, 1, getContentResolver().insert(uri, values));
                return true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

getting following exception

```
09-12 01:36:58.279: W/System.err(2474): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/sounds/media/Ring.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at com.appsworld.shivringtone.SplashActivity.saveas(SplashActivity.java:307)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at com.appsworld.shivringtone.SplashActivity$C02832$C02821.onClick(SplashActivity.java:166)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1108)
09-12 01:36:58.280: W/System.err(2474):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
```

Please help me to resolve. I have also given proper permission in manifest file. I have downloaded some app from market place and tried to run on my device which exactly working fine but I don't know why in my case this code is not working. Is it because I don't have SDCARD or something else?

Comment: Are you sure the directory path is correct? If the directory path is not present, you will get this exception. I'm guessing the directory `sounds/media/Ring.mp3` is not found in your LeEco phone.

Comment: @SripadRaj, for that i am already creating directory if its not present. check if (!new File(path).exists()) {
                new File(path).mkdirs();
            }

Comment: what is line no `307` in your code?